# Javascript link in drupal view

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-views

I'm telling the view to display a field with the NID contents. I'm telling it that I wish to "Rewrite the output of this field" and I enter:

```
<a href=”javascript:void(0);”  onclick="javascript: approve([nid])" >Approve</a>
```

When viewing the page, all the javascript has been stripped. How do I get views to accept javascript in the link, or what other way can I use to display a link?

Note: Custom Text field doesn't work either.

Comment: Not an answer, but javascript: URLs are outdated (and you don't need it in onclick, either). `<a href="#" onclick="approve([nid]); return false;">Approve</a>`

Comment: Interesting. And that won't cause the page to jump to the top?

Comment: The `return false` bit prevents that. In jQuery, you can use `event.preventDefault()` to do the same thing.

Comment: I dont agree with you. I just implemented the example you gave, and it still jumps?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution! http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield

From the description:

> This module provides some useful (views)fields.
>   Available (views)fields:
>   Markup
>       Field that allows usage of custom text and the input filter system.
>   PHP code
>       Field that allows usage of custom PHP code (with access to view's database result)
>   Rownumber
>       Field containing rownumber (respects pagers).